# MySQL and Python, insert rows into a table

Tags: python, mysql

The `Horse` table has the following columns:

- ID - integer, auto increment, primary key
- RegisteredName - variable-length string
- Breed - variable-length string, must be one of the following:  Egyptian Arab, Holsteiner, Quarter Horse, Paint, Saddlebred
- Height - decimal number, must be between 10.0 and 20.0
- BirthDate - date, must be on or after Jan 1, 2015

Insert the following data into the `Horse` table:

```sql
RegisteredName  Breed           Height  BirthDate
Babe            Quarter Horse   15.3    2015-02-10
Independence    Holsteiner      16.0    2017-03-13
Ellie           Saddlebred      15.0    2016-12-22
NULL            Egyptian Arab   14.9    2019-10-12
```

Table exists and does not need to be built.

```sql
CODE UPDATE;

INSERT [INTO] Horse (RegisteredName, Breed, Height, BirthDate)
VALUES ('Babe', 'Quarter Horse', '15.3', '2015-02-10')

INSERT INTO Horse (RegisteredName, Breed, Height, BirthDate)
VALUES ('Independence', 'Holsteiner', 16.0, '2017-03-13')

INSERT INTO Horse (RegisteredName, Breed, Height, BirthDate)
VALUES ('Ellie', 'Saddlebred', 15.0, '2016-12-22')

INSERT INTO Horse (Breed, Height, BirthDate)
VALUES ('Egyptian Arab', 14.9, '2019-10-12');
```

Now errors lie in line 4. What am I missing?

Comment: "Now errors lie in line 4." - what does that mean? How is the code you've shared even related to Python?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you first have to create the table with:

```
CREATE TABLE Horse(RegisteredName, Breed, Height, BirthDate)
```

Then:

```
INSERT INTO Horse 
VALUES ('Babe', 'QuarterHorse', '15.3', '2015-02-10')
```

I could be wrong but it worked for me.

*Are you using SQL or Python?

Comment: SQL I think? My ZyBooks made it sound like it's python in SQL.

Comment: Can you show your full code?

Comment: at the moment, that was my full code. I'm working on building the table currently to see if that was the missing element.

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO Horse (RegisteredName, Breed, Height, BirthDate)
VALUES('Babe', 'Quarter Horse', 15.3, '2015-02-10'),
('Independence', 'Holsteiner', 16.0, '2017-03-13'),
('Ellie', 'Saddlebred', 15.0, '2016-12-22'),
(NULL,'Egyptian Arab', 14.9, '2019-10-12');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.